# Generating a webpage from an SQL database depending on what link was clicked (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a webpage that will list multiple items (I will call this the list page), which upon being clicked, will generate a specific webpage (I will call this the item page) with data retrieved from one entry in an SQL database. I'm new to web programming and do not fully understand how to accomplish this.

To retrieve the data, I have:

```
function returnData($dataID){
    $specific = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM USERS where First ='$dataID'");
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())  //grabs and puts in assoc array
        {
            $a = $rows['First'];
            $b = $rows['Second'];
            $c = $rows['Third'];
              return $b;
        }
}
```

I have the return there immediately because I am just testing and only have unique entries in the database. I plan to call this function in another PHP page which for my purposes I believe is my "index" (what I've called item page) in the header,index,footer setup. I believe I need to use GET in a manner like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['action'])){
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $action = basename($action);
        include("$action.htm");
    }
```

On the list page, would I then have to make each clickable link reference to "?action=id"? I get 404 errors when trying to access the link via address bar and clicking it does nothing. Am I not allowed to link in such a manner? Additionally, I've removed the index portion and simply placed the appropriate SQL code to see if anything will display on a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to ref the link is:

```
phpindex.php?action=(whatever)
```

As for the rest of the code, it does work, although I'm sure poorly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with that form of mysql query on the first block of code so I'll stay away from fixing it unless you want me to expand on what I'm familiar with.

As far as the second page I would use something like

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
$action = basename($action);
include($action .".htm");
}
```